# provide type better annotation in JS when argument has default

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I'm working in a legacy code base with JS files, not TS. However I'm adding tsc to validate types.

one way that TS inferring types for arguments is based on default value. So a function like

```js
function doSomething(withProp = 5) {
  ...
}
```

`withProp` is presumed to *always* be a number, so trying to call `parseInt(withProp)` would not be happy.

I know I can use JSDocs to correct types, but in this case I'm dealing with an anonymous function deep inside a getter tree for Vuex. Is there another way to provide types for these args?

Comment: In JavaScript code, the fact that the default value of a parameter is a number doesn't necessarily imply that that's the only parameter type the function accepts.

Answer (score 1):

`withProp = 5` in your code reflects the `default` value of `arg`, but it doesn't mean to be always a number `type` of `arg`.

If you pass any `string` or `object` as an argument, its type might be changed according to the incoming argument.

The best way checking your type is to create an utility function which detects the type of your argument. ( you can use If ... else if.. else )
And then you can invoke this function inside of getter for validating the incoming argument.